# How to JOIN a column in codeigniter using a specific condition

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, join

I have 2 tables.

- admins
- profile

In the `admins` table, there is `admin_id` and I want to join it with `profile` which has a field `identifier`. Lets suppose that `admin_id =1000000`. I want to join it like this.

```
$this->db->select('*')->from('admins')->join('profile', 'admin.id = "ABC".admins.admin_id."U"')->where('email', $username)->where('password', $password)->where('status', 1);
```

admin_id is 1000000
identifier is ABC1000000U

How can I join these 2 tables based of these?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
$this->db
  ->select('*')
  ->from('admins')
  ->join('profile', 'CONCAT("ABC", admins.admin_id, "U") = profile.identifier')
  ->where('email', $username)
  ->where('password', $password)
  ->where('status', 1);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using JOIN then both columns must have same `datatype` and there should be REFERENCE between them, as per your required result you can try below CI code,

```
// create where condition array
$where = array('email'=>$username,'password'=> $password,'status'=>1);
// if there is admin_id then add more conditions in it
if(isset($admin_id) && $admin_id){
    $where['a.admin_id']=$admin_id; // from admins table
    $where['p.identifier']='ABC'.$admin_id.'U'; // from profiles table
}
$this->db->select('*')
     ->from('admins a,profile p') // join not required
     ->where($where); // add where at a glance
```